# Bind a value to a custom control inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, ascx

I can't see where I have gone wrong with this so I'm looking for some help.

I'm trying to use my custom control with parameters in a repeater.  The parameter is always null when I debug it, even though the same expression returns data on the previous line of code.

Inside my control I have:

```
public string paddockName { get; set; }
```

And I am assigning it on my asp.net page as:

```
<mp:Historical runat="server" paddockName='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
```

I made the previous line of code as per the below and it worked fine, so the expression is correct.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I've seen a previous question [ASP.NET: Bind a value to a custom user control inside a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979840/asp-net-bind-a-value-to-a-custom-user-control-inside-a-repeater) which is almost exactly the same as my problem, but the answer just says "I did a small test and I got it working if the ProductID is a string." and that doesn't help me figure out how they got it to stop being null when debugging.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code you've posted. At what point are you checking the property value?

Comment: I am checking the property value in an onclick of a button on the control.  I've checked that it's not being clobbered at pageload or anything like that - if I pass through a string as the property instead of the databinding, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the data bound value is lost when the button postback happend.  The property value is only set for the duration of the page request that has the DataBind() call.  The button click is a new page request.  The .NET controls store the bound value in ViewState so they are available on a post back.  You can do the same thing by changing the way the property is stored.

```
public string paddockName {
    get { return Convert.ToString(ViewState("paddockName")); }
    set { ViewState("paddockName") = value; }
}
```